# extract different parts of a document

Tags: input, data-structures

I'm doing my phd right now and I want to prepare a dummy folder for new research projects. I have one problem where I don't know how to start:

For a journal submission I need several slightly different versions of a finished paper:

- Complete Paper (Name + Title page + Text + Bibliography + Tables + Graphics)
- Anonymous Paper (Title page + Text + Bibliography + Tables + Graphics)
- Manuscript (Text + Bibliography + Tables + Graphics)
- Pure Text (Text + Bibliography)
- Tables (Tables)
- Graphics (Graphics)
- Tables and Graphics (Tables + Graphics)

It is very annoying and error-prone to always keep the individual documents on the same level. Ideally, I would like to make a change in the whole paper and all other files will do the same. But I use the \ref{} command in my text to create a link between tables and images. So if I want to create a "Pure Text" version I have to replace a "?" with the corresponding numbering for all references by hand.

Is there an elegant approach to solve this problem? The \input command is familiar to me, but I cannot solve my problem so easily because of the \ref issue.

Comment: Hi @Martin and welcome to TeX-SE. I don't know if I understood it correctly, but if you need to replace text there are some option with "regexp" commands. Some editors have a "Project Find and Replace Feature", such as TeXstudio. You can do it in NotePad++ in "Find Files" and I have a personal Matlab code to Search and Replace a set of strings in a set of files. It is similar to NotePad++ but you can run it over and over.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  The label values that will be used for `\ref` are stored in one or more `.aux` files as `\newlabel`.  After a successful run of the complete file, you can create a new file (under a new name) and copy into it all the `\newlabel` lines for the tables and figures, and then `\input` that file in the preamble of your stripped-down file.

Answer (score 1):

The package [extract](https://ctan.org/pkg/extract?lang=en) is doing exactly what you want to do.

Comment: Extract si Great as long as you don't need to tikzertalize.

Comment: Agree. I am also having lots of trouble with extract due to tikzexternalize.